# White space showing around slider - I have tried two different sliders and same thing happens?

Tags: css, slider, whitespace, flexslider, bxslider

http://www.mhinteriors.com.au/new/index.html

flexslider 2 showing white space around the slider on initial load of webpage and when page is refreshed?  If I click on about page and go back to the home page the white space disappears.

If I refresh the page the white space returns.

I have removed flexslider 2 and loaded bxSlider instead and the exact same thing is happening?

Comment: doesn't appear to be happening in firefox only chrome?

Comment: I dont see any white space. MAybe the whitespace you see is because of the images you have. They seem to have a white border. Check this image i took from your website on a black BG. http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/a52dv/

Answer (score 0):

It happens when I use Firefox, but it seems like your images contain most of the actual whitespace around them.

To remove the excess border, change this in the `jquery.boxslider.css` file:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
border: solid #fff 5px;
}
```

to

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
border: solid #fff 0px;
}
```

That will remove the border, from what I can tell.

**EDIT**

Also, change the `left:-5px` to `left:0px`under the same.

Another thing, to prevent the arrows from getting "cut off", set the right and left positions to `5px`:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
left: 5px;
background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
right: 5px;
background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still the same effect I even removed all css from 
   .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport { 
   }
and it still shows weird white space even the banner becomes glitchy when I scroll up and down.

Comment: I moved the slider to http://www.mhinteriors.com.au/new/working-files/slider.html

Comment: It seems to only be doing the glitchy scrolling in Chrome. Everything looks fine to me. Are you certain your original images do not have the weird white space in them? Because they look like they do [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5rvee/) click that link

Comment: I think I have solved this issue I changed all my z-index and the problem seems to have ceased